# regex to match any characters and numbers but without space and @ symbol

Tags: regex

i just wanna a regex can help me validate input allow any characters numbers but no spaces and @ symbol, any idea?  I am not very good at regex, I know use ^\S+$ to avoid space, and use ^[^/\()@]*$ to avoid @ symbol, but how to combine these two together? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negated character class.

```
^[^\s@]+$
```

Explanation:

```
^             # the beginning of the string
 [^\s@]+      #   any character except: whitespace, '@' (1 or more times)
$             # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj, thanks for your reminding, I have accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Add `\s` to character class

```
^[^@\s]+$
```

- `\s` matches spaces.
- The negated character class `[^ ]` ensures anything other than `@` or space is matched

[**Regex Example**](https://regex101.com/r/yU2xH3/1)